# Why doesn't my sbt project dependency work? (insists on trying to fetch it remotely)

Tags: sbt, scala.js

I'm wanting to have a bridge for Scala.js and Snap.svg in an sbt project, but also including demo code for the bridge.

When doing `demos/compile` sbt starts to say that it cannot resolve the dependency. It looks like it's trying to reach the bridge as if it was a publicized, external project but it's right here, and it compiles.

What am I doing wrong?

Removing the publishing-specific files does not seem to bring a change.

Directory structure:

```
├── build.sbt
├── project
│   ├── (PublishToBintray.scala)
│   ├── build.properties
│   ├── build.sbt
│   ├── project
│   │   └── ...
│   └── target
│   │   └── ...
├── (publishing.sbt)
├── scalajs_demos
│   ├── main
│   │   └── scala
│   │       └── clock.scala
│   └── target
│       └── ...
├── src
│   └── main
│       └── scala
│           └── org
│               └── scalajs
│                   └── snapsvg
│                       ├── SnapSvg.scala
│                       └── package.scala
└── target
    └── ...
```

build.sbt:

```
scalaJSSettings

name := "Scala.js Snap.svg"

normalizedName := "scalajs-snapsvg"

version := "0.01"

organization := "org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.4", "2.11.1")   // note: not tested with 2.10.x

libraryDependencies +=
  "org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.6"   // TBD: probably need it, just like jQuery bridge does

ScalaJSKeys.jsDependencies +=
  "org.webjars" % "Snap.svg" % "0.3.0" / "snap.svg.js"

homepage := Some(url("http://snapsvg.io/"))

licenses += ("Apache 2.0", url("https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/master/LICENSE"))

//---
// bridge (main) project
//
lazy val bridge = project.in( file(".") )

//---
// demos project
//
lazy val demos = project.in( file("scalajs_demos") ).dependsOn(bridge)
```

What goes wrong in sbt:

```
> demos/compile
[info] Updating {file:/Users/asko/Hg/scala-js-snapsvg/}demos...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs#scalajs-snapsvg_sjs0.5_2.10;0.01 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs#scalajs-snapsvg_sjs0.5_2.10;0.01
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/asko/.ivy2/local/org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs/scalajs-snapsvg_sjs0.5_2.10/0.01/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scalajs/scalajs-snapsvg_sjs0.5_2.10/0.01/scalajs-snapsvg_sjs0.5_2.10-0.01.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs#scalajs-snapsvg_sjs0.5_2.10;0.01: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last demos/*:update for the full output.
[error] (demos/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs#scalajs-snapsvg_sjs0.5_2.10;0.01: not found
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 27.7.2014 22:57:22
>
```

One more thing, the `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs" % "scalajs-sbt-plugin" % "0.5.0")
```

Comment: Why the `% "test->test"` in `.dependsOn(bridge % "test->test")`? It seems like you want a dependencies between the `compile` configurations (no `%` needed), not from the test config to the test config.

Comment: Well, that was unnecessary for this issue and maybe in general as well. I removed the notion now, but it does not affect the problem - I still get the same dependency error even without it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The root cause of your issue is that the `bridge` project uses `scalaVersion := "2.11.1"` (as specified by your `build.sbt`, but your `demos` project uses the default `scalaVersion` (which is 2.10.2 in sbt 0.13, IIRC). The `dependsOn` relation gets confused when it tries to relate projects with different scalaVersions. See this issue: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1448

You probably thought that `scalaVersion := "2.11.1"` in the root `build.sbt` would apply to all subprojects. But that's not true, it only applies to the subproject rooted in `.` (here, `bridge`). You have to also specify this setting (and others you want shared) either as arguments of the `settings()` method of `demos`, or in the `scalajs_demos/build.sbt` file.

Comment: Amazing, thanks Sébastien. Will try at home but it must be this. Would never have solved it!

Comment: I wish I can upvote this more than once. **Having scalaVersion in the root build.sbt doesn't mean it applies to all subprojects!**